# Waiver for medication during race?

Tags: racing, tour-de-france

During the 2017 Tdf, Tim Wellens abandoned during stage 15 due to bad allergies and not being able to breathe.  The commentators said that his team would not "give him a waiver" to take allergy meds.

What exactly is a "waiver for medication"? Why does one need one during a major race and why would Wellens' team not give him one?

I can see how something like pseudoephedrine or a steroid could cause someone to test positive for prohibited substances in a race with strict substance rules and testing.  Is this the entire reason that he was not granted a waiver?

I would think Wellens could/should have taken something benign to help, like a benedryl, in order to continue the race.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd want to take benedryl during a race. It impairs concentration and temperature regulation. Most likely the drugs in question are corticosteroids, which many consider performance enhancing. There was quite a hubbub last year concerning Sky's use of waivers for corticosteroids, I can imagine a team wanting to avoid that.

Comment: You assume there is a drug that would help him and not fail a drug test.

Comment: See [Therapeutic Use Exemptions](https://www.wada-ama.org/en/what-we-do/science-medical/therapeutic-use-exemptions) for more information on this.

Comment: Also if it's going to take time to kick in (not an expert in benadryl) he might be out of at least the stage anyway.  So it might have to be something stronger/injected.

Comment: Apparently Wellens refused the TUE: http://www.cyclingweekly.com/news/racing/tour-de-france/tim-wellens-refuses-tue-treat-illness-abandons-tour-de-france-342198 rather than being denied it by his team.

Comment: My respect for him increases based on this - cycling's history of riders doping is disappointing, so this is a refreshing to see someone steering the straight and narrow.

Answer (score 1):

There is asthma due to exercise. (Exercise-induced asthma). So one can have lung problem simply due to huge exercise. (not very likely in this case, but possible).

Waiver for meds in my view is "permission" to take a medication. E.g., epilepsy drug to prevent you from having seizure during the race.